# Composer is broken: Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

Tags: php, composer-php

I can't get composer to work. It also fails when I try to deploy to Heroku.

```
$ composer update
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

$ rm -r ~/.composer

$ composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
Changed current directory to /home/Chloe/.composer
Using version ^1.1 for fxp/composer-asset-plugin
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fxp/composer-asset-plugin (v1.1.4)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

$ composer update
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist
```

I tried the steps in [Composer throws [ReflectionException] Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437837/composer-throw-reflectionexception-class-fxp-composer-assetplugin-repository-n) and [Updating composer throws exception Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579559/updating-composer-throws-exception-class-fxp-composer-assetplugin-repository-npm), but it still fails.

I also ran `composer self-update` and it still doesn't work.

PHP 5.6.19, Composer version 1.1-dev, Composer version 1.0.2 2016-04-21 12:30:18

Comment: just tried with that version of composer and the v1.1.4 of `composer-asset-plugin`, I've no problem. Can you share your composer.json?

Comment: Here is the `composer.json`: http://pastie.org/private/4vvvpacgx5pzfrqd4kpg

Comment: Some good hints from the Yii2 dev: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34939821/148844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you require a version of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` that's now broken with composer >= 1.0.

```
"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.0",
```

Since you've installed it globally, you can remove it from your `composer.json`.

Comment: I already tried deleting that line, but it still doesn't work. It still gives the same error message.

Comment: `composer show -i`: `[ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist`. Yes, I ran `composer update` after I deleted that line in `composer.json` and saved.

Comment: please, delete `vendor` and `composer.lock`, then re-install with `composer install` and retry. Or do it with `composer update --no-plugin`

Comment: OK I deleted `vendor/` and `composer.lock` and the version line, but it gave me an unrelated error: http://pastie.org/private/lythgvfk2it5nu3yo3ohw

Comment: have you installed the plugin with `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1"`? what's the output of `composer global show -i`?

Comment: `composer global show -i` yields `Changed current directory to /home/Chloe/.composer
You are using the deprecated option "installed". Only installed packages are shown by default now. The --all option can be used to show all packages.
fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.1.4 NPM/Bower Dependency Manager for Composer`. I finally fixed the unrelated error by running the 'global require' again and now `composer update works`. For some reason `composer` seems to suck. I wish it worked as good as `gem` for Ruby.

Comment: You were using an old version of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` locally, that's it. Now that composer is stable, no more BC like that would be introduce.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error. Try

```
composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

this worked for me